# Logitech MX anywhere 2S mouse: buttons not recognized by xev

Tags: fedora, mouse

I'm using Logitech MX anywhere 2S mouse on Fedora 27, but only the left/right buttons and wheel up/down buttons are recognized by xev. I'm looking for a way to map the three remaining buttons.

[image: Here're the buttons of that mouse]

I want button 3 and 8 in the picture above mapped. Can someone help me?

**[EDIT]**

So I tried `evtest` mentioned in the comment, and I got

```
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1513145549.654477, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90003
Event: time 1513145549.654477, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 274 (BTN_MIDDLE), value 1
Event: time 1513145549.654477, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
9:48 / 16:31
Event: time 1513145549.806472, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90003
Event: time 1513145549.806472, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 274 (BTN_MIDDLE), value 0
Event: time 1513145549.806472, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1513145555.448316, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90005
Event: time 1513145555.448316, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 276 (BTN_EXTRA), value 1
Event: time 1513145555.448316, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1513145555.594292, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90005
Event: time 1513145555.594292, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 276 (BTN_EXTRA), value 0
Event: time 1513145555.594292, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1513145558.152251, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90004
Event: time 1513145558.152251, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 275 (BTN_SIDE), value 1
Event: time 1513145558.152251, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1513145558.298240, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90004
Event: time 1513145558.298240, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 275 (BTN_SIDE), value 0
Event: time 1513145558.298240, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Those are buttons at 2 and 8 in the picture. And I use `xbindkeys` to remap those buttons and it works.

**Edit**

After I updated some packages and rebooted, I can't find those buttons in `evtest`, why's that?

It seems that I need to re-connect my mouse to make it work and I don't even need `xbindkeys` started to do so.

Comment: Do they generate events at all? Look at the raw input device to see.

Comment: How? Is it xev and press the corresponding buttons?

Comment: @Turgon try with `evtest` too... (`lsinput` will help you find the right device.)

Comment: In addition to `evtest`, look at the new lines in `dmesg` after you connect the mouse and/or the controller (you didn't say what kind of mouse it is). If there's a hidraw device, look at that. There was some other question where it turned out the Logitech wireless controller produces two HID devices, and some mouse events end up on one, some on the other. Maybe try to find that question for details.

Comment: @Turgon I know it's been a long time, but where you able to resolve this issue? I have the exact same problem (I need to re-connect the mouse to make it work)

Comment: @Ali sorry, it's been such a long time, I can't recall whether or not I resolved the issue. I'm not even using the same mouse and system anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have any of the mouse buttons listed in your .xbindkeysrc yet as they won't not show up in xev if you do (at least on my system).

You can also try upgrading your Linux kernel as this mouse is relatively new.

Here are the actual button numbers from xev:
[image: key mapping for Anywhere 2s]
Source: https://deepmi.me/etc/18869/

Comment: Actually, I think the problem in my **EDIT** has something to do with my mouse. Sometimes when I switch the mouse to my laptop (Windows) and then switch back to my PC, those buttons simply won't work. In any case, I can make them work by reconnecting the mouse.